# Control for adjusting ratio between quantities

Tags: gui-design, desktop-application

I am looking for a ui control type which allows adjusting the ratios between at least 3 different scalar quantities.

For example, adjusting the composition of a chemical solution, such that a user can set it to be composed of 50% X, 30% Y and 20% Z.

Currently I am using 3 sliders ranging from 0 to 1 for X, Y and Z, and then normalizing the values in the sliders to derive the actual composition.

I am looking for a more compact and intuitive alternative, ideally in a single control. An ideal solution would not take up space for each component, as there are multiple such sets to display in a limited area.

Furthermore, the context is a real-time environment, where the user must make adjustments quickly, as if in a video game. In this sense, sliders provide a good response as they're easy to grab and drag.

Accuracy is less important than responsiveness and intuitiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think the other answer with input is a good option as it's more accurate and still pretty fast once the user gets used to tabbing (and shift-tabbing). Although I would set them out horizontally to allow for more sets on screen at a time.

But as you don't like it, and you may have a valid reason not to (for example, no keyboard input), then my suggestion is to look at a multi-value slider. Something like this:

[image]

The main issue with this however, is that you are going to need to play around with the display labels to ensure they don't overlap while still indicate clearly which section they belong too.

One possible workaround for this is to make 0% values a fixed with, as can be seen in my second example above where Y = 0%.

Comment: I think this is a promising direction. I can see the downsides of it as you've clearly explained but I will definitely try to make an implementation of this.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why not just use three input fields w/ a total?

- It requires the least physical dexterity, unlike a slider.
- It also affords the most precise input.
- You can use tab index so the user doesn't have to use a mouse if they are on desktop.

[image]

It's a fairly common pattern (you often see this on budgeting and financial sites, when allocating adjustments to a portfolio) and drives home the fact that x, y, and z are parts of a whole.

Comment: While a good answer, it draws focus to the lack of context in my question. This solution is less than ideal in my case because (1) there are many such ratio compositions to display in a small space (2) accuracy is not very important (3) user responsiveness is crucial, they need to adjust the ratios quickly based on real time events. I will add more context in the question.